# Language not available on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, localization, itunes, app-store-connect

I've successfully translated my App to Spanish and Catalan. Both versions (in addition to the english one) work very ok. I'm preparing the submission and, when I'm to add the new Catalan version, to my surprise I cannot choose this language from the scroll down menu, although I was able to select it on Xcode when working on the translation.

So, how am I supposed to release the catalan version?. I know I could select spanish and fill the field with the catalan version, but then I cannot fill in the spanish one.

Anyone here with experience on the matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a comment not an answer: if XCode clearly makes a distinction and the submission environment does not, you'd better call (not email) Apple on it. Get back to SO, it might be something useful for future reference.

Comment: That might be a good idea. Does anybody have the number? I'm not having much finding it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "versions" here, I assume you're just talking about localizations within one single application.

If so, the user would simply need to purchase your application from the App Store, run it on their device, and if they have Catalan as a primary language, your Catalan localization would be used.

iTunes Connect does not support Catalan as a store language yet, which is why you can't post a Catalan translation of the store listing, but it still should display in the proper language on the user's device. According to the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), the following languages are currently supported for localization of the application description:

- English
- Spanish
- German
- UK English
- Canadian English
- French Canadian
- Brazilian Portuguese
- Australian English
- French
- Mexican Spanish
- Portuguese
- Dutch
- Italian
- Japanese
- Simplified Chinese
- Russian
- Swedish
- Korean

If you wish for Catalan to be added as an additional language option in the App Store, please file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com .

Comment: Yeah, I meant Localizations. I figured out something like this was going on. What I´ve finally done is to add the spanish description under LantinAm Spanish and catalan under spanish. The thing is that catalan is a co-oficial language in Spain. So now people in Spain will only see the description in catalan, which it´s not so good. I´m going to fill a bug report as I thing iTunes should support any language the device can support. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I have similar problem. I did localization for English and Lithuanian languages. And how users which are in Lithuania will be able to Lithuania version if in the setting here is no way to set default language to Lithuania? If it is possible then what needs to do?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can localize your app in a language that is not available in iTunes, is to create a separate app just for this country and enter the info in the language. Not ideal, because now you have 2 apps to take care of: one for all available language and one just for this language.